# How to update record and childs on extjs treegrid?

Tags: extjs

I have a treegrid and I want to update just one node with its childs. So I have tried like this:

```
store.load({
  node: store.getNodeById(1)
});
```

That updates childs, but not the node itself. So how can I update node and childs? It would be best if it would require just one request to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn´t any way to do it by configuration, it just works as design. What you can do is a little trick after load the node's children in order to manipulate the tree nodes to update the node itself manually.

See the images. They show the behaviour you expect.

[image]
[image]

This is working okay in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lontivero/jBTWn/3/

Basically, the idea is, as I just said, manipulate the tree after load the children. In my example this is done by:

```
        var node = store.getNodeById(1);

        store.load({
            node: node,
            callback: function(newRecord) {
                var parent = node.parentNode;
                parent.insertBefore(newRecord[0], node);
                parent.removeChild(node);
            },
            params: {
                json: Ext.JSON.encode(updated_data)
            }
        });
```

Good luck!

Comment: any comment? is this what you need?

Comment: Hmm it refreshes all tree and I clicked 'Try it' twice and it left only new homework block.. lotery tickets disapeared. Sorry I forgot to answer but I found another solution http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?206335-extjs-4.1-tree-refresh-a-specific-node&p=812368&viewfull=1#post812368

Comment: I will accept your answer if you will fix these problems: update and refresh only one node without refreshing whole tree and would work more than one time :D

Comment: Yes, because the point is showing you how to refresh a node with its children. It shows you the technique for doing that. If you click twice 'Try it' it won´t work because the example has a hardcoded id because it is a demo. And it doesn´t refresh the whole tree, it only refresh the node with id=1.

Comment: Me bad didn't thought about that. Don't know with way is bettermaybe yours as it doesn't require overwrite.